# Play audio file on the telephone through a modem

Tags: php

how can i Play audio file on the telephone through a modem
with php?

Comment: I would imagine the process will be very hardware-specific, so if you want to get a valid answer, I think you'll need to give more hardware specifics.

Comment: Relevant ServerFault question: http://serverfault.com/questions/152241/using-modem-for-sending-voice-recording/189047#189047 (one of mine)

Answer (score 0):

PHP alone can't do this.  You'll need some kind of 3rd-party program that you can execute through PHP's exec command.

Comment: This is incorrect. Any programming language that can open a serial port and send things to it can do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the appropriate AT command to the modem to tell it to expect an audio file, then you need to send the audio file to the modem.